# Why is this CSS Translate3d Animation Janky?

Tags: css, animation, transition, hardware-acceleration, translate3d

I can't figure out why the performance of this css transition using a hardware accelerated property `transform: translate3d();` is not working smoothly.  Perhaps because the elements are absolutely positioned?  I don't know...

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/danielnice/full/jMojqd/)

Can someone please explain to me why and how to fix? You can see the bad performance if you use Chrome's dev tools -> timeline, record, then run the animations by click the screen.

Here is a screencap of my dev tools.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your columns aren't broken out of the document flow. You can see the horizontal scrollbar in the initial state. Try adding the following code to ensure they aren't triggering a redraw and scroll.

```
.columns {
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: This significantly helped the performance.  It makes sense now that I think about it.  I missed the fact that it was adding a scroll bar there by causing multiple redraws.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things you can do.

If you know these are going to be changing consistently and you don't have many you can add:

```
will-change: transform;
```

To your `.columns .col` rule. [(read about `will-change` here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

Also change `ease` on the transform to `ease-in-out`.

Finally your page size is changing which forces hard re-draws the simplest way to solve this in your case is to add this to your stylesheet:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is a [codepen with all of those applied](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXwoNV).

Comment: Yep the overflow was biggest impact to performance, I missed the fact that it was added a scroll, stupid me, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be related to the easing property that you're using. Try setting the transition to *ease-out*

```
col {
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but that didn't do the trick, still the same FPS profile, I have tried `linear` and other easing methods as well.

Comment: Just spit-balling here, but I did find another reference for smoothing out CSS animations (https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d). I don't know if it'll help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Appreciate the link, that is a good trick however I don't need it in my case sense I defined `translate3d` on the col elements already.  That sticks it on its own hardware accelerated layer so I don't need another property to do that.